# UpdateQuery not working with no errors

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I can use these `UpdateQuery` on `WinForms`, now I convert it to ASP.NET Version and use this `UpdateQuery` again and not work. Others `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` all works well, only update, also no error have given.

```
protected void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "UPDATE patient SET ID=?ID, NameCH=?NameCH, NameEn=?NameEn, NRIC=?IC, Tel=?Tel, Email=?Email, Sex=?Sex, Occupation=?Occupation, Married=?Married, Address=?Address, Allergies=?Allergies, LTM=?LTM, MH=?MH, Other=?Other WHERE ( 'ID'=?ID )";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ID", ids.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?NameCH", CHName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?NameEN", ENName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IC", NRIC.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Tel", TEL.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", Email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Sex", sex.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Occupation", occupation.Text);
    if (married.Checked) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Married", "YES");
    } else {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Married", "NO");
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Address", address.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Allergies", Allergies.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?LTM", ltm.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?MH", medicalhis.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Other", record.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home.aspx/Update");
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean for `?ID` to literally equal "ID"?

Comment: nvm i found that another problem , postback problem

Comment: You will have to describe a lot better what you mean by "does not work". If I have to guess blindly, I would say, your view element representing the id field `ids.Text` might not have the value that you expect it to have when you run this particular query. Also, no need to `SET ID=?ID`

Comment: Improved title and formatting